# Web browser is being "strict" for operations on undefined variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, undefined-behavior, use-strict

If the variable `foo` is undefined, normally I can do things like:

```
!foo;
foo === undefined;
foo !== 'some value';
```

However, the code base that I am working on now has something in it that seems to instruct the browser's interpreter to throw an exception for any operation on an undefined variable other than this:

```
typeof foo !="undefined";
```

I'm working in the same browsers that I normally work in (Chrome and Firefox). But I'm coming on to this project in the middle this time instead of starting from scratch. It is a dJango project using Backbone.js, underscore, handlebars, jQuery, yepnope.

Could this behavior be due to the instruction `"use strict"` appearing somewhere in the global namespace? I did a search in the project for the text string "use strict" and found it in some code that seems to come from twitter:

```
    Files: bootstrap.js
           script.js
    From:  http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#transitions
```

I also found it in the json2 file. However I'm pretty sure this file didn't cause me problems last time I worked with it:

```
    File: json2.js
    From: http://www.JSON.org/json2.js
```

For all I know, this isn't even caused by the inclusion of "use strict" somewhere...

Any ideas?

Thanks so much!

Comment: NITPICK: typeof is an operator, not a method call. It does not need `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an important difference between *undefined* and *undeclared*.

```
function test() {
    var foo;
    if (foo) { /* not executed */ }
}
```

This is fine because `foo` is declared, but its value is *undefined*.

```
function test() {
    if (foo) { /* exception! */ }
}
```

This will throw an exception (`ReferenceError`) because `foo` is not *declared*.  (Unless there is a `window.foo`.)

Comment: Strange. Why is `window.foo treated` differently than `foo`?

Comment: @ChrisDutrow `window.foo` is a **property** of the `window` object. See also: [What is the difference between a global variables and attributes of the window object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274856/what-is-the-difference-between-a-global-variables-and-attributes-of-the-window-o)

Comment: I think what is confusing me is that all global variables are properties of the window object. Is this not correct?

Comment: In browsers, `window` is the global scope.  So if you write `if (foo) ...`, first local scope (any `var`s inside the current function) is checked for any declared `foo`s.  If there aren't any, the scope of enclosing functions (if any) are checked for `foo` (aka closures).  Finally, the global scope (the `window` object) is checked for `foo`.  If it does not have `foo`, then `ReferenceError` is thrown.

Comment: @ChrisDutrow What's not correct? Your confusion, or the truth that global variables are properties of the `window` object?

Comment: @Rob W - I'm confused about what is different between: foo and window.foo.

Comment: They're properties of whatever the global object is (which, in browsers, is `window`).  But with the qualifier, JS at least knows where to expect to find the variable and that you're intentionally using a particular property (which might as yet be undefined).  Without a qualifier, `foo` could be pretty much anywhere, and if it's not defined anywhere along the scope chain yet, it's probably an error.

Comment: @cHao - It sounds like there is a defined scope chain. At the end of it is the "window" object that holds all global variables. A variable that is not found anywhere else, would default to being in the "window" object as opposed to "pretty much anywhere". So I'm still not sure why "foo" is being interpreted different than "window.foo"?

Comment: @ChrisDutrow `window.foo` is a read operation on a `"foo"` **property** of the `window` object. Under normal circumstances, properties can always be read, even if they're never set. When you're trying to read the value of the **`foo` variable** (no prefix), an attempt is made to find the **declaration** of the `foo` variable. When the variable is neither explicitly nor implicitly declared, the variable lookup fails, and a `ReferenceError` occurs.

Answer (score 2):

When a variable is undeclared, you **cannot** use it in comparisons.

```
undeclaredvar = 1;
```

is the only thing that works: `undeclaredvar` is implicitly declared in the global namespace.

Strict mode declarations inside a function will never "leak" the strictness to the global scope. So, `"use strict";` in Twitter bootstrap / JSON2 won't affect the strictness of your script.

Comment: More correctly, you cannot use *undeclared* variables in comparisons.  Variables with undefined values can certainly be used in comparisons.

Comment: @josh3736 Woops, that slipped through. Should never have happened. Thanks for mentioning.